# Search bar is constant when we scroll the table and the index value(A,B,C,D,E etc) is above the search bar

Tags: iphone, ios, scroll, tableview, uisearchbar

Please tell me how we can implement this.Search bar in top after that there is a tableview.In a table there is secction header and index value. Search bar is constant when we scroll the table and the index value(A,B,C,D,E etc) is above the search bar.

Comment: What do you mean by "search bar is constant"?

Comment: when we scroll table .search bar is not scrolling.it is fix. it is same as contact list in iphone. .

Answer (score 0):

```
This will give you standard searchBar and solve your problem.

UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[searchBar sizeToFit];
searchBar.delegate = self;
searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

UISearchDisplayController *searchDC = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
```